# Sum of series in python

Tags: python

How do write a program in python to print sum of the following series:1+1/4+1/7+1/10+1/13+1/16+1/19+1/22+1/25.
I tried it using the sum of series formula by taking 1st term as 1, last term as 25 and number of terms as 9. I use the if loop and it is not running.

Comment: It would help to show what you've already tried, but please don't spam multiple unrelated language tags.

Comment: Try `sum(1 / x for x in range(1, 25+1, 3))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can only possibly fix problems in code if we see that code; `if` is not a "loop"; and "it is not running" does not describe a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
number_of_terms = 9
total = sum(1/(1+i*3) for i in range(number_of_terms))
```

Or, if you want to provide start, end and step, use:

```
start = 1
end = 25
step = 3
total = sum(1/i for i in range(start, end+1, step))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of values, you can use the sum() function:

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
total = sum(list)
print(total) # 15
```